# select distinct without including duplicates

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, distinct-values

I have a table looking like the following and I need a table with the unique values of Id and another one with the Id values repeated.

My problem is that I can't use a "select distinct" statement because it will include the repeated Id values once.

Id        letter

80004   A

80008   B

80019   C

80086   A

80086   C

80086   B

80066   A

80099   C

80100   A

80087   C

80087   A

What I need is to divide the previous table into two tables looking like:

Id        letter

80004    A

80008   B

80019   C

80066   A

80099   C

80100   A

and

Id      letter

80086   A

80086   C

80086   B

80087   C

80087   A

Comment: I don't understand the logic of this split. Please expand.

Comment: I just want a table with those Id that only have one group (like 80004, 80008...) and their group. I also need another table with those Id that can have different groups (80086 and 80087) and their groups (A,C and B for 80086, and C and A for 80087).

Comment: But why is `80004,80008` is a group and not `80004,80086` ?? What's the logic behind this

Comment: instead of saying that 80004 and 80008 I'd say that is a letter (I edit the question)

Answer (score 1):

By using a sub query:

```
select A.id , id_value from

( select id from mytable group by id having count(id_value) >1 ) A
inner join mytable using(id)


select A.id , id_value from

( select id from mytable group by id   having count(id_value) <=1   ) A
inner join mytable using(id)
```

Here is the [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd1dc/2)